# Show input type="radio" inline style - with icheck-me class [icheck Plugin]

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to align the input radio type inline.. but still i can't able to make them inline.. it comes in next line.

[image: Check image here]

This is the coding unit.

```html
<tr>
    <td>Display on Homepage</td>
     <td>
         <div style="display: inline;">
             <label>
                  <input type="radio" class='icheck-me' name="show" value="Yes" data-skin="flat" data-color="orange" checked> Yes 
              </label>
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" id="radio-inline" class='icheck-me' name="show" value="No" data-skin="flat" data-color="grey"> No 
              </label>
          </div>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I have put on an answer, but CBroe is right. Check those links out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
<label class='box'>
              <input type="radio" class='icheck-me' name="show" value="Yes" data-skin="flat" data-color="orange" checked> Yes   

          </label>
          <label class='box'>
              <input type="radio" id="radio-inline" class='icheck-me' name="show" value="No" data-skin="flat" data-color="grey"> No 
          </label>
```

CSS:

```
.box{ display:inline-block; width: 50px;} .icheck-me{ display:inline-block; float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the inline on the labels too

```
<div>
    <label style="display: inline;">
        <input type="radio" class='icheck-me' name="show" value="Yes" data-skin="flat" data-color="orange" checked> Yes 
    </label>
    <label style="display: inline;">
        <input type="radio" id="radio-inline" class='icheck-me' name="show" value="No" data-skin="flat" data-color="grey"> No   
    </label>
</div>
```

This is just an example, it's not recommended to add these properties in the style attribute - you should add it to a new class or add the `display: inline;` to the `icheck-me` class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:block` to get the radio buttons underneath each other. Also, align the text to the top right of the cell by using: 'style="vertical-align: top;"'

So, your code would look like this:

```
<tr>
  <td style="vertical-align: top;">Display on Homepage</td>
  <td>
  <div>
      <label>
      <input type="radio" class="icheck-me" name="show" value="Yes" data-skin="flat" data-color="orange" checked> Yes   
  </label>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-inline" class="icheck-me" name="show" value="No" data-skin="flat" data-color="grey"> No 
  </label>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And CSS:

```
.icheck-me{
  display:block;
  }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8kLn1Lta/)